# Get profile picture from Facebook using social-auth

Tags: django, django-socialauth

I am implementing social login in my application and I am already getting normal fields as First Name, Last Name on Facebook and LinkedIn... Now I want to get the profile picture. I did it for LinkedIn and it is working perfectly, i can see the URL on the extra fields from the database.

I am trying to do the same with Facebook, as I saw here https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/django-social-auth/Mee8H8HhLQk
defining

```
FACEBOOK_PROFILE_EXTRA_PARAMS = {'fields': 'picture'}
FACEBOOK_EXTRA_DATA = [('profile', 'profile')]
```

But when i did this, somethings got messed up. I am not able anymore to get the first name and last name in my user table as I was doing before these two lines of code. Does anyone know why this problem is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The picture is under `http://graph.facebook.com/<user_id>/picture`. The `user_id` is given by the FacebookBackend.